# How to translate Makefile statements which involve shell commands to Scons

Tags: python, makefile, scons

The following Makefile, untars libcurl, configures it, creates a static library and links to the main program.

How do I do translate it to Scons?

I tried to do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7341908/scons-invoke-the-build-of-a-makefile-project) but of no avail.

Snippet of a Makefile:

```
LIBCURL:=./lib/libcurl.a

all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(LIBCURL)

$(LIBCURL):
    cd ./packages; tar jxfv curl-$(CURL_VER).tar.bz2; ln -sf curl-$(CURL_VER) curl; \
    patch -d curl -p1 < ../patches/curl-trace-info-error.patch
    mkdir -p $(CURL_BUILD);
    cd $(CURL_BUILD); ../../packages/curl/configure --prefix=$(CURL_BUILD) \
    --without-libidn \
    --without-libssh2 \
    --disable-ldap \
    --disable-ipv6 \
        --enable-thread \
        --with-random=/dev/urandom \
        --with-ssl=/usr/include/openssl \
        --enable-shared=no \
        --enable-ares=$(CARES_MAKE_DIR) \
        CFLAGS="$(PROF_FLAG) $(DEBUG_FLAGS) $(OPT_FLAGS) -DCURL_MAX_WRITE_SIZE=4096"
    make -C $(CURL_BUILD); make -C $(CURL_BUILD)/lib install; make -C $(CURL_BUILD)/include/curl install;
    mkdir -p ./inc; mkdir -p ./lib
    cp -a $(CURL_BUILD)/include/curl ./inc/curl
    cp -pf $(CURL_BUILD)/lib/libcurl.*a ./lib
```

Comment: BTW, why bother to use  `scons` if you already have a *working* `Makefile`?

Comment: This Makefile is from curl-loader which used Makefile. It's not mine. I am using scons and stumbled upon this which is what I want to do

Comment: You aren't showing how your approach in SCons looks like. Using the Command builder is actually the right thing to do...so the question is how exactly you did it, and which errors you get. Only then, someone can try to help you out.